# Solution for a sinus problem

Tags: medications, common-cold, nose, sinus

I am a 30 year old lady. Some doctor told me that I have some problem in my nose bone and it may be a sinus. When I get cold my nose bone pain a lot while breathing and have watery eyes. Whenever I inhale, I feel some pain in right nostril. How to ease these at home. I am staying at a hostel. Kindly suggest me. Is there any medicine for the immediate relief.